# PluginResolutionException: Plugin .url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, jdbc, wildfly

I am trying to run `mvnw clean compile` on a rather old project.
The whole line is

```
../mvnw clean compile -Dflyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/my_database -Dflyway.user=some_user -Dlyway.password=xxx -Dflyway.outOfOrder=true flyway:migrate -f pom.xml -U -X
```

This gives me the following error

> BUILD FAILURE
>
> [ERROR] Plugin .url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact .url=jdbc:postgresql:jar://localhost in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
>
> org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin .url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact .url=jdbc:postgresql:jar://localhost in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

And then further down

> Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact .url=jdbc:postgresql:jar://localhost in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

This is the part of the `pom.xml` where I add the dependency (which is what I can find on Maven https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.2.19)

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
   <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
   <version>42.2.19</version>
</dependency>
```

And for what its worth, this is defined in the Wildfly properties for the database (`database.properties`)

```
database.test.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/my_database_test
database.test.username=some_user
database.test.password=xxx

database.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5431/my_database
database.username=some_user
database.password=xxx
```

Comment: You probably need to escape some characters in there and/or quote them. You've got a path separator of `/` defined and a a file separator of `:`.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins So something like `database.url=jdbc\:postgresql\:\/\/localhost:5431\/my_database_test`? No luck....

Comment: You might need to quote it. This looks like a command line issue. I don't know what the flyway plugin is though.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins hm... still the same error.

Comment: @four-eyes - Just FYI re your deleted `await` question: Having your call to `func1` wrapped in an anonymous function would still have worked. I'd have to see what you actually tried to explain why it didn't work, but that (alone) wasn't it -- unless you never called the wrapper function. :-D Anyway, just for the avoidance of doubt, that is indeed how you handle rejections of the promise you're awaiting: `try`/`catch`(/`finally`). (Or more often: Don't, let the error propagate to the caller. But you know what I mean. :-) ) Happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for coming back to me :) I am not sure if I understand `Or more often: Don't, let the error propagate to the caller`. What do you mean by this? I am kind of new to error handling and making it "failproof" :)

Comment: @four-eyes - Errors propagate up through the call chain. So if `a` calls `b` calls `c` and an error occurs in `c`, if `c` doesn't catch that error, it propagates up to `b`; if `b` doesn't catch that error, it propagates up to `a`. So you only want to catch and handle it at the uppermost level that makes sense. Often you'll see people put error handlers (`try`/`catch` blocks) in (say) `c` even though `c` can't do anything about the error; they have it return some kind of "failed" value instead. But that's usually not best practice. Instead, if `c` can't meaningful handle the error, it...

Comment: ...shouldn't try to. Instead, leave it to `b` or `a`. Often, this means you only have error handlers in two places: 1. Entry points (the main initial code of your page/app and event handlers), and 2. Places where the error *can* be meaningfully handled. Almost any time you see `try { /*...*/ } catch (e) { return null; }` or similar, it would have been better not to have the `try`/`catch` at all. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ah okay, I understand. Thanks for the clarification. What if `a` calls `b` and `b` calls `c`. All three of them are `async/await` constructs. I would (maybe naively) put in `a`, `b` and `c` a `try/catch`, because I do not want my programm to fail, if i.e. `c` provokes an error. In the `catch` of all of them (`a`, `b`, `c`) I would add a `Promise.reject(new Error("Some message"))`. Is that the corret way?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The problem with that construct is (I think) that if let's say `c` provokes an error, causing the `Promise.reject(...)` to be called, it propagates up the call chain to `a` which then provokes its `catch` block with its own error message. This makes it hard to trace where the error occured.

Comment: @four-eyes - I don't see why, most JavaScript engines provide useful async traces now. If you can give me a concrete example, I might be able to help with that?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Your right, it worked as you suggested. I think I had something messed up in my head. Thanks a lot for your support. I am amazed how people like you like to share their knowledge and do not try to "show off" or make you feel bad because they know more! I really appreciate it!